# Concatenate files in .bundle file with Gulp and NOT Visual Studio

Tags: html, visual-studio, gulp, bundle

I've been passed down a project built through Visual Studio and it contains an **index.html.bundle** file. In Visual Studio these files are usually built by running the build tool and this automatically creates the **index.html** page. However I am running this project on a Mac and can not get access to this tool (or is there a similar tool?).

I am trying to concatenate the files inside the .bundle file into one index.html page using [gulp-bundle-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bundle-file) but, nothing is being created.

My **gulpfile.js** has the following task where the .bundle file is at the root and I am trying to output it in the root as well

```
gulp.task('bundles', function() {
return gulp.src('/*.bundle')
    .pipe(bundle.concat())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('/'));
```

});

Not sure if it matters but, my .bundle file is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bundle xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://vswebessentials.com/schemas/v1/bundle.xsd">
  <settings>

    <!--Determines if the bundle file should be automatically optimized after creation/update.-->
    <minify>true</minify>

    <!--Determine whether to generate/re-generate this bundle on building the solution.-->
    <runOnBuild>true</runOnBuild>

    <!--Specifies a custom subfolder to save files to. By default, compiled output will be placed in the same folder and nested under the original file.-->
    <outputDirectory />

  </settings>
  <!--The order of the <file> elements determines the order of the files in the bundle.-->
  <files>
    <file>/header.html</file>
    <file>/templates/file1.html</file>
    <file>/templates/file2.html</file>
    <file>/templates/file3.html</file>
  </files>
</bundle>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the description of the [gulp-bundle-file plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bundle-file) that you linked, you can see that the plugin expects plain text .bundle files where every line contains one file, like so:

```
file1.js
some-dir/file2.js
my-dir/another-bundle.js.bundle
```

It doesn't handle the type of XML file produced by Visual Studio that you  included in your post.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, is there another tool that you'd suggest that could handle this?